# PremiumV2 not found Error when Deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have configured and been using VSTS to deploy to Azure. But recently, I have none of my releases are succeeding and are failing at the Azure Powershell script task with an error.

```
##[error]Requested value 'PremiumV2' was not found.
```

I have done some digging and came to know that `PremiumV2` is a new tier of subscription for App Services from Azure. But I'm on Standard Tier and haven't changed any subscription plans.

Is this being faced by anyone else or did I miss to make a configuration change based on some Azure update?

**Logs**

```
##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1 -Global
##[command]Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName SUBSCRIPTION_NAME -SubscriptionId SUBSCRIPTION_ID -Certificate SUBSCRIPTION_CERTIFICATE -Environment AzureCloud 
##[command]Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId SUBSCRIPTION_ID
##[command]& SCRIPT_PATH -website WEBSITE_NAME -webJobName WEBJOB_NAME -webjobzip WEBJOB_ZIP_PATH
10/5/2017 10:33 AM - Removing all jobs running on the website.
True
10/5/2017 10:34 AM - Script to upload WEBJOB_NAME webjob started.
##[error]Requested value 'PremiumV2' was not found.
##[error]Requested value 'PremiumV2' was not found.
##[section]Finishing: Azure PowerShell script: FilePath
```

Comment: What're tasks of the build/release? What's the detail code in Azure Powershell task? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Can you provide the build/release log?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Added the logs above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by there is some app service using "PremiumV2" app service plan in your Azure Subscription even though you are not using it and in the "Azure Powershell Script" task you are using "Azure Classic" connection type and old Azure Cmdlets to get the app service while the old cmdlets does support the new features well. To fix this issue, you can change the connection type to "Azure Resource Manager" and update your powershell script to use Azure RM cmdlets.

Comment: As I understand, if any other app in our subscription is on Resource Manager, the other cmdlets will fail to use the older classic deployment scripts?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot get your point. What do you mean about "the other cmdlets will fail to use the older classic deployment scripts"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant. 'other app release defintions'. 

I notice that we would need to rewrite our powershell scripts to upload the jobs to app service.

Comment: If these apps were created with Azure Classic, you can still use the old deployment script. But as more and more new features introduced, you may get similar issue like this post. So we recommend you to update the release definition to use Resource Manager.